# SVN export fails when run remotely

Tags: svn, psexec, collabnet, winrm

We have a .bat file that does an SVN export command which contains the credentials for the SVN repo. The file sits on each server's C:\ drive.  When a user is logged into the box and runs it locally, this script runs fine.

When run via winrm or psexec, we're getting this error:

```
svn: E175013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL <URL>.  
svn: E175013: Access to '<URL>' forbidden
```

The credentials in the command are not the problem. The credentials include the account's domain.

The SVN server is Collabnet Subversion 1.5.1, running on Apache 2.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems psexec runs with some lower credentials. Passing in a username and password to run the command as fixes this problem:

```
psexec.exe \\hostname -h -u domain\admin_user -p password "C:\command.bat"
```